# State in Singleton object changes between workers in Scala

Tags: scala, jvm, apache-beam, beam

First of all: I'm aware this is not an ideal way to approach this situation, but I have a Beam pipeline in Scala with a singleton object which has a state, and the state is accessed by multiple workers. I have to use this approach because it's a non-serializable object, but the question isn't about the approach itself.

The object, lets say, look like this

```
object Foo { 
   var bar: Option[MyConfig] = None
   
   def init(myConf: MyConfig) = this.bar = Some(myConf)
}
```

this method is first called at the entrypoint of the pipeline. It is the second step after loading the config, let's say its like this:

```
    Object Main {
    
    def main(args: Array[String): Unit = {
      */ elided config load */
      */ elided pipeline creation */
      Foo.init(myConfig)
      pipeline.apply("SomeTransform", ParDo.of(new SomeTransform))
    }
}
```

And `SomeTransform` has a method which has to execute if `Foo.bar` is defined, however, every time a `SomeTransform` is created and I reach this point, the state is seemingly lost and the conditional step is skipped.

I've added logging to confirm that:

1. The state IS changing at the base of the pipeline, and this is a singleton object, so it should remain so through the same JVM.
2. The state (`Foo.bar`) equals to `None` when `SomeTransform` checks for its status

I could also call the init method inside the transform, but I'm afraid about concurrency issues.

Comment: Instead of exposing the state to be accessed, you should make it private to only let Foo handle the internal state. The method to get the state and the one for update it should use some synchronous mechanism to avoid concurrent issues

Comment: the state is private, I just forgot to add the private modifier on bar. But it is private and can only be changed via the init method. I cannot let the object handle its state 100% from itself because it needs to be passed a valid config.

Comment: I can't imagine the whole context. You have a singleton object with an internal state that will be accessed by different workers. The internal state can only be changed through the public API of the singleton. Why this one can not handle the state? Sounds like you have a shared value between different workers. If you don't add a mechanism to avoid race condition, you will probably end up having them. Maybe you can add more details of the things involved. How about some diagram? If it is possible a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)